# Authenticate OpenFire against outside service

Tags: java, authentication, xmpp, openfire

I am trying to authenticate OpenFire log in requests with an outside service. I have successfully done this using a custom AuthProvider implementation (below). However, this only works from the WEB UI. When a client connects via the Spark client, it still seems to perform the old method (username, token, digest) and not just username,password. What other changes need to be made to my java class to get it to do what I need it to do? Also, you can see I have a PrintWriter that never executes when the Spark client attempts to connect, this also tells me that it isn't being redirected to this authenticate function. Before you ask, I have modified the Spark client to do the connection.login(String,String) function instead of the connection.login(String,String).

Thanks for any help.

**DMAUth.java:**

```
package org.jivesoftware.openfire.auth;

import java.io.PrintWriter;

import org.jivesoftware.openfire.user.UserNotFoundException;

public class DMAuth implements AuthProvider {

    public boolean isPlainSupported() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return true;
    }

    public boolean isDigestSupported() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return false;
    }

    public void authenticate(String username, String password)
            throws UnauthorizedException, ConnectionException,
            InternalUnauthenticatedException {
        try {
        PrintWriter writer = new PrintWriter("log.txt", "UTF-8");
        writer.println("Username: "+username);
        writer.println("Password: "+password);
        writer.close();
        }
        catch (Exception e) {

        }

    }

    public String getPassword(String username) throws UserNotFoundException,
            UnsupportedOperationException {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return null;
    }

    public void setPassword(String username, String password)
            throws UserNotFoundException, UnsupportedOperationException {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    public boolean supportsPasswordRetrieval() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return false;
    }

}
```

Error that shows in info.log:

```
2014.09.09 11:05:08 org.jivesoftware.openfire.nio.ConnectionHandler - ConnectionHandler reports IOException for session: (SOCKET, R: /192.168.10.155:55212, L: /192.168.10.157:5222, S: 0.0.0.0/0.0.0$
java.io.IOException: Broken pipe
        at sun.nio.ch.FileDispatcherImpl.write0(Native Method)
        at sun.nio.ch.SocketDispatcher.write(SocketDispatcher.java:47)
        at sun.nio.ch.IOUtil.writeFromNativeBuffer(IOUtil.java:93)
        at sun.nio.ch.IOUtil.write(IOUtil.java:65)
        at sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.write(SocketChannelImpl.java:487)
        at org.apache.mina.transport.socket.nio.SocketIoProcessor.doFlush(SocketIoProcessor.java:414)
        at org.apache.mina.transport.socket.nio.SocketIoProcessor.doFlush(SocketIoProcessor.java:332)
        at org.apache.mina.transport.socket.nio.SocketIoProcessor.access$500(SocketIoProcessor.java:45)
        at org.apache.mina.transport.socket.nio.SocketIoProcessor$Worker.run(SocketIoProcessor.java:488)
        at org.apache.mina.util.NamePreservingRunnable.run(NamePreservingRunnable.java:51)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:744)
```